# Running a coroutine function from a noncoroutine function in Python?

Tags: python, syntax-error, coroutine, discord

I am using the discord.py to interact with discord.

```
def hi():
    await client.send_message(channel, message)
```

gets a syntax error, unless I write "async" when I the hi() function.
I really don't understand this, pls help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can schedule a coroutine in an event loop. You can not call them or await them from inside a non coroutine.

Let's check the following code:

```
import asyncio


async def greetLater(name, delay):
    await asyncio.sleep(delay)
    print("Hello {}!".format(name))


def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(greetLater("masnun", 10))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

In  the above code, `greetLater` is a coroutine. We can't directly call it from the `main` function. What we need to do here is to create an event loop and then schedule the coroutine there. We use the `asyncio` module to help us create the event loop and run the coroutine.

Further references:

- http://masnun.com/2015/11/13/python-generators-coroutines-native-coroutines-and-async-await.html
- http://masnun.com/2015/11/20/python-asyncio-future-task-and-the-event-loop.html

(Disclaimer: Links to my personal blog posts on the topic, you can google for more references)

Comment: Is passing the loop into the function where it can then be closed okay? What I am making might be used by other people and I think you are more experienced than me.

Comment: I didn't fully understand the scenario but passing the loop in general is fine.